# Installing CLD libary on windows and bind to Python

Tags: c++, python, github, language-detection

I have a need to make use of Chromium's Compact Language Detector library within a Python script.

AFAIK, there are two projects that leverage this library, but I have been having troubles with getting either of them set up on a Windows 7 machine.

I had some similar problems with [Mike McCandless Original Project](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/10/language-detection-with-googles-compact.html) ([GoogleCode](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-compact-language-detector/source/search?q=build.win.cmd&origq=build.win.cmd&btnG=Search%20Trunk)), but I then spotted [Matt Sanford fork on the same Project](http://mzsanford.com/blog/introducing-libcld) ([github](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld)).  For the purpose of this question, I will focus on Matts project, as it seems to have been updated more often (but happy to get an answer that works for either project).

- Downloaded [the project](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld) as a zip, and extracted to my local drive.
- Ran vcvarsall.bat from CMD
- Then ran the build.win.cmd batch file.  This [ran ok](http://pastebin.com/cRbNy6VY).
- Copied the resulting libcld.lib to ports/python/cld.lib
- Tried running the [setup.py](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld/blob/master/ports/python/setup.py) but it returns with the following against line 12.

  exceptions.TypeError: **init**() keywords must be strings

++EDIT++
Found this [issue](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld/issues/19):

> setup.py fails on Windows. The hackish solution to fix this is to make
>   pkgconfig return the dict {'define_macros': [('WIN32',None)],
>   'libraries': packages}

Im a bit of a rookie, but not entirely sure on the steps to implement this hack.  Can anyone give me some slightly more verbose steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this patch ([works for me](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cld)):

```
diff --git a/ports/python/setup.py b/ports/python/setup.py
index e1950c3..889f21a 100644
--- a/ports/python/setup.py
+++ b/ports/python/setup.py
@@ -9,7 +9,10 @@ def pkgconfig(*packages, **kw):

 module = Extension('cld',
                    ['pycldmodule.cc'],
-                   **pkgconfig('cld'))
+                   define_macros=[('WIN32', None)],
+                   libraries=['libcld'], 
+                   include_dirs=['..\\..\\'],
+                   library_dirs=['..\\..\\'])

 setup(name='cld',
       version='0.031415',
```

Comment: I ran the 32bit installer (im using 32bit Python) and can now import CLD from python, but its not behaving correctly and errors.  Im new to git, where do I run the above code, just copy n paste into a CMD?

Comment: You probably need to install the [Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29).

Comment: It's probably fastest to apply the patch manually: replace the line `**pkgconfig('cld'))` in `setup.py` with `define_macros=[('WIN32', None)],libraries=['libcld'],include_dirs=['..\\..\\'],library_dirs=['..\\..\\'])`

Comment: Ive tried running this on a separate machine (which has similar setup) and running setup.py in same manner, gives me some errors.  Any chance you could comment on the likely cause of these?  http://pastebin.com/Cy4uYCtL

Comment: Ended up using the .exe you linked to.  I used VS2010 on both machines, and python is 2.7 on both.  Not sure how up to date the exe is, but it serves the purpose.  Thanks